# CSS Display Inline block is not displaying inline

Tags: html, css, angular, forms, bootstrap-4

I have below html and CSS where i want the dropdown to be inline but its not displaying inline.

```css
.project Type{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<form class="smart-form">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
      <label class="project Type" >Project Type</label>
      <label class="project Type" >
        <select type="text" class="padding-5">
          <option *ngFor="let t of epmodel.ProjectType" value="{{t.id}}">{{t.type}}</option>
        </select>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Olay9.png)

[image]

Comment: There is probably not enough room in you column for both to sit side by side. As a test, remove all classes from your column `div` and only include `col`. Like this: `<div class="col">`

Comment: your selector is not correct, it should be :`.project.Type` instead `.project Type`.  `class="project Type"` is here 2 classes not a single one. ||| `.project Type` is trying to select an  `Type` tag inside a parent with the class  `project`.

Answer (score 1):

classes can't have spaces in its name, because it will consider it as a nested class in the css. So, for your example is looking for an element `Type` inside a block with a class `project` In this case you may want to use `projectType` class and then your css should be:

```
.projectType {
  display: inline;
}

<label class="projectType">...</label>
```

Comment: I don't have space in there..I had issues while posting in stackoverflow....it accepted with space

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

.project.Type { display: inline-block; }

You may refer here for more info:
https://css-tricks.com/multiple-class-id-selectors/

Answer (score 0):

In css declaration, class name must not be seperated words, just like your javascript variable name.

If you are using Bootstrap, you can just the proper class name in html as below, no need to write style code.

```html
<form class="smart-form">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
      <label class="d-inline" >Project Type</label>
      <label class="d-inline" >
        <select type="text" class="padding-5">
          <option *ngFor="let t of epmodel.ProjectType" value="{{t.id}}">{{t.type}}</option>
        </select>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Reference [Bootstrap display utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/display/).

If you are not using Bootstrap, you can write below css code:

```css
.d-inline {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: flex;` and it is recommended to use CSS classes without spaces.

`.projectType{
    display: flex;
}`

Answer (score -1):

```
.projectType{
    display: inline;
}
```

Also change your html class reference to match `class="projectType"`

Comment: Both the names are matching....display: inline is not working as well